# How to open an excel file and past rest api response that is already in csv format into the new excel?

Tags: c#, excel, csv

I fetch from a rest API a response which is already in csv format.
I managed to open an excel file but the silly thing is, I don't find anywhere how to past it  without sending everything within the first cell...

So far, I have this code:

```
//if status is 200201, that means that my csv is generated
// API_Helper is my class, FeedData is my function that fetches the final response
if (statusResponse == "200201")
        {             
            string finalResult = API_Helper.FeedData(FeedJobID, accessT);
            Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
            Excel.Workbook xlWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Add();

            Excel.Worksheet xlWorkSheet = (Excel.Worksheet)xlWorkBook.Worksheets.get_Item(1);
            xlWorkSheet.Cells[1, 1] = finalResult;
        }
```

If I use this above code, basically I have all my response within the first cell instead having all my csv populated. I'm trying either having a classic csv format or having my data populated properly into a normal excel using the comma separated.

Does anybody have an idea ? Let me know if you need more info. I'll be please to add complement if needed.

Comment: Sounds like you will have to parse and iterate over finalResult. Several tutorials/answers already on SO.

Comment: Instead of pasting the whole CSV into 1 cell, why not just load the file into Excel?

Comment: @Neil, because at the end, finalresult is concerted into a string. I don't think it is possible to load a string into excel right ?

Comment: @AnthonyG. , I'll check. Do you have a quick idea how to parse a csv reponse ?  I use Newtonsft.json to sort json response but as it's a csv I don't think I can use Newtonsoft.json ?

Comment: CsvHelper nuget package is well liked and documented, I have used it on massive CSV files and it is simple to implement. https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/ as @Neil commented, writing the string to file, then opening that file in Excel is also an option if you don't need to modify the data in any way.